# How to use "ToFeedIterator" in Linq?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using `DbContext` to query `Cosmos` container. I have a scenario where I would get comma separated string with N ids and I want to query them efficiently. Majority of example suggests`container.GetItemQueryIterator` but in my case, I can use `query.ToFeedIterator()` (unless there is a way and I am not aware of it).

To do that, I am trying to use `.ToFeedIterator` but I am getting following error:

> `"ToFeedIterator is only supported on Cosmos LINQ query operations (Parameter 'linqQuery')"` error and not sure how to resolve

My goal is to query Cosmos as efficiently as I can when I receive the huge number of data.

**References:**

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs#L101
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp

**Questions:**

- Is this the correct way to use `FeedIterator`?
- How can I pass partition key in my query?
- Let's say these string comes up with 1000 ids (or more), is this the most efficient way? OR is there any other way to do that?

**Code:**

DbContext.cs

```
public class CosmosDbContext: DbContext
{
   
    public CosmosDbContext(DbContextOptions<CosmosDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    #region DbSets

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region user
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToContainer(nameof(User).ToLower())
            .HasNoDiscriminator()
            .HasPartitionKey(user => user.userId)
            .HasKey(user => user.id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(user => user.id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasPartitionKey(record => record.userId);
        #endregion

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.cs

```
public async Task<User> GetExistingDocumentsAsync(string userIds, bool withNoTracking, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var query = withNoTracking ? _dbContext.User.AsNoTracking() : _dbContext.User;

    var userDocs = new List<User>();
    var ids = userIds.Split(",").Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
    var feedIterator = query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.userId)).ToFeedIterator(); // Throws error here
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults) 
    {
        foreach(var document in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            userDocs.Add(document);
            // Iterate through documents
        }
    }
    
    return userDocs;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of variable "query" in UserRepository.cs?

Comment: @ShahidSyed It is `IQueryable`

Comment: Interesting. I use GetItemLinqQueryable on Cosmos Container and same where clause works. If query.ToFeedIterator() works without the Where clause then it might be a limitation with the DBContext implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToFeedIterator()` method can be used with *Container* class object to convert LINQ query to iterator, as it is implemented with abstract methods `GetItemQueryIterator()`, `GetItemQueryStreamIterator()` etc. But same is not implemented in *DbContext* class. This is the reason when we use `toFeedIterator()` with *DbContext* object it throws the following exception

> *ToFeedIterator is only supported on Cosmos LINQ query operations (Parameter 'linqQuery')*

We can still use LINQ quires with *DbContext* object using `ToListAsync` or `ToList` methods with Cosmos Db and Entity Framework Core,

Below is the sample code using PartitionKey, which is working as expected with the use of `WithPartitionKey()` and `ToFeedIterator()`.

As mentioned earlier in this case I have used `ToFeedIterator()` with `GetItemLinqQueryable()` using *Container* class object.

```
CosmosClient _client = new CosmosClient({CosmosDBConnectionString});
var _database = _client.GetDatabase({DatabaseName});
var _container = _database.GetContainer({ContainerName});

var userDocs = new List<User>();
var ids = userIds.Split(",").Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

var feedIterator = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<User>()
.WithPartitionKey(partitionKey.ToString())
.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.userId))
.ToFeedIterator();
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var document in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            userDocs.Add(document);
        }
    }
```

**Model (User.cs)**

```
public class User
    {
        public string? id { get; set; }
        public string? userId { get; set; } //PartitionKey
        public string? name { get; set; }
    }
```

Using `contains()` should work fine for large datasets as well.

Comment: This works if I start using `new CosmosClient` but since I already have `DbContext` implemented, I do not want to use two patterns in my logic. If this is the limitation with `DbContext` then I would like to explore efficient options for my current logic. Thank you for providing this example.

Comment: I am not sure what `.WithPartitionKey(partitionKey.ToString())` is doing. `ids` is collection partitionKeys. How are you utilizing that in this line? (not sure where `partitionKey` is defined)

Comment: @GThree Please have a look on [WithPartitionKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.cosmosqueryableextensions.withpartitionkey?view=efcore-7.0). It only supports single string partition key value as a parameter.

Comment: @GThree Using LINQ `contains` is a way to apply filter on partitionKey or other fields.